# Choosing $a,b,c,d$ from $1,2,\cdots,20$ such that $a + c = b + d$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How many ways can you choose 4 numbers $a,b,c,d$ from $1,2,\cdots,20$ such that $a+c = b+d?$ Changing the order of $a,c$ and $b,d$ doesn't result in a new pair.

---

I wanted to try and find a bijection, but I'm not sure how to and what 1-to-1 correspondence this set should be with. Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction, not a full answer?

Comment: Do you require $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ to be all different ?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: First find how many pairs sum to $5,6,7,8$ by hand.  You may notice a pattern.

Comment: You told us that $1+5=2+4$ is the same as $5+1=4+2$.  How about $4+2=5+1?$  Is that different?

Comment: Maybe it's this http://oeis.org/A002623 (I'm counting $5,1,4,2$ as not distinct from $4,2,5,1$).

Answer (score 0):

The sums range from $2$ to $40$.  You can consider each sum separately and add them up.  As an example, $6=1+5=2+4=3+3$ has three ways to represent it.  If you prohibit $2+4=4+2$ and consider $1+5=2+4$ the same as $2+4=1+5$ there are ${3 \choose 2}=3$ such equations where the sum is $6$ and generally if there are $n$ ways to represent a given sum there are $n \choose 2$ ways to form an equation.  Then note that there is $1$ way to get $2$, $1$ way to get $3$, $2$ ways to get $4$ and generally $\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$ ways to get $n$ for $n \le 21$, then we start counting down.  In this model, the total number of solutions is  $$2\sum_{i=2}^{20}  {\lfloor\frac n2 \rfloor \choose 2}+{10\choose 2}=615$$
where the last term comes from a sum of $21$ that doesn't have a partner.  If you don't like my choices in the third sentence, this approach will work but needs to be modified.

Comment: Shouldn't you be summing $[n/2]$ choose $2$, not just $[n/2]$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  yes, it should

Comment: OK, so, as I suspected, it's http://oeis.org/A002623 (with a different offset).